# Header Redirection in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, header

I am (trying to) writing some code to redirect a user within my website depending on their device.

If the user is on a mobile, I want to add a directory "/m/" to the beginning of the current path and redirect them to the same file in the new location (with the same url parameters if possible but not essential)

ie [www.mysite.com/shop/items1/shop.php?para1=somestuff](http://www.mysite.com/shop/items1/shop.php?para1=somestuff)   ==>   [www.mysite.com/m/shop/items1/shop.php?para1=somestuff](http://www.mysite.com/m/shop/items1/shop.php?para1=somestuff)

**The error I'm getting is :**

*This site can't be reached*

*The webpage at*

*http://dev4/shop/items1/shop.php?uncd=c74f474e2c396da2993cfb344007ad6a&iid=014ec54f3746fd834da71ad21e76a0fa&crtfn=D2*

*might be temporarily down or it may.......*
*ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT*

**My code is**

```
<?php
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
 include ($path . '/includes/functions.php');
 $pathloc = '';      // Variable used for new folder location  ie /m/ for mobile  /t/ for tablet
 $device= device();  // function to get the type of device
 if ($device=="IsMob")
    {$pathloc = '/m';
    header("Location: " . $path . $pathloc . dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . "/" . basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php"));
         }

?>
```

I'm using host headers "dev4".

I suspect that the directory and file location are wrong. I've tried outputting the string to the screen to inspect the url that is being built and all looks fine so I'm a little stumped.

Any help is gratefully received.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

As is always the way, as soon as I post the question up I've been struggling with for 2 days, I work out the answer myself.

Reference for anyone it may help.

```
header("Location: http://Dev4" . $pathloc.dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']). "/". basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], ".php"));
```